# how do i convert Lat and Long to uk postcode with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to make use of HTML5 geolocation for a project I'm working on.

It seems pretty straighforward to get the Lat and Long of where a user is, via geolocation.

Problem is, I need to convert this to a UK postcode, and am strugging as I'm trying to learn javascript.

The code I have working is:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    displayPosition, 
    displayError,
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
  );
}
else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
}

function displayPosition(position) {
  alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var Long = position.coords.longitude;
    var inputField = document.getElementById("addressInput");
    inputField.value = Lat + Long;
}

function displayError(error) {
  var errors = { 
    1: 'Permission denied',
    2: 'Position unavailable',
    3: 'Request timeout'
  };
  alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
}
```

I've found this site, whihc does exactly the kind of thing I want to achieve:
http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html

Can anyone give me some tips on how to get this working?

Any advice would be great

thanks in advance

=========================
Amended code:

```
        //var long = '50.**************', lat = '0.**************'
        var Lat='';
        var Long='';
        var coordsObj = {coords:{latitude:Lat, longitude:Long}};

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            displayPosition, 
            displayError,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
          );
        }
        else {
          alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }

        function displayPosition(position) {
            console.log(position, position.coords)
            console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
            var Lat = position.coords.latitude;
            alert(Lat);
            var Long = position.coords.longitude;
            alert(Long);
            var inputField = document.getElementById("addressInput");
            inputField.value = Lat + Long;
            return [Lat, Long];
        }           

        function displayError(error) {
          var errors = { 
            1: 'Permission denied',
            2: 'Position unavailable',
            3: 'Request timeout'
          };
          alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        }

        function reverseGeoLookup(lon, lat) {
          var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
          req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
          req.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if(req.readyState == 4) {
                  var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
                  for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
                      for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                          var component = result[i].address_components[j]
                          if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                            var out = document.getElementById('output')
                            out.innerHTML += component.long_name
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          req.send()
        }

        var latlng = displayPosition(coordsObj)
        reverseGeoLookup.apply(this, latlng)
```

Comment: First you need a data source giving you the locations of all UK postcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Google Maps [reverse geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). This allows you to map a lat, long pair to a set of addresses. For example:

```
function reverseGeoLookup(lon, lat) {
  //make a ajax request -- in prod just use whatever libraryyou have to provide this
  //probably jquery's $.get
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
  //put the longitude and latitude into the API query
  req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
  //this is just the result callback -- it's the function arg to $.get, essentially
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == 4) {
          //again jquery will parse for you, but we want the results field
          var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
          //the maps API returns a list of increasingly general results
          //i.e. street, suburb, town, city, region, country
          for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
              //each result has an address with multiple parts (it's all in the reference)
              for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                  var component = result[i].address_components[j]
                  //if the address component has postal code then write it out
                  if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                    var out = document.getElementById('output')
                    out.innerHTML += component.long_name
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  //dispatch the XHR... just use jquery
  req.send()
}
```

I put this example into a js fiddle too, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ef72Q/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for that kieran.. works a charm!
I'm trying to get it to work with a Lat and Long defined by geoLocation though.. And I can't seem to get the Lat and Long variables to populate with values.. they keep returning null. 
Theres something wrong with my scope I think??

Comment: Trying to get displayPosition to populate the Lat and Long values.. So the rest of the code then uses these values as the Lat and Long..

Comment: Hi sure -- sorry for the delay, I get the feeling we are in slightly different time zones : ). Basically because the position needs to be from the navigator.geolocation we need to put the geolookup into the callback -- it's asynchronous. What was happening was we called the lookup at the bottom of the script with the variables we set, rather than wait for `navigator` to give us the values. See this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JCvF/)

Comment: Thats so cool! Its working great now!! Thanks for all your help man.. Its really taught me a lot too. You can see a working example of my fledgling webapp @ fooder.co.uk...(Its very Beta) Let me know what you think!
Last thing I'm trying to understand is this bit:
   reverseGeoLookup.apply(this, latlng)
Wondering what 'this' is referencing.. and also where the latlng argument comes into it??
Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 6):

There's now a free UK government alternative to the other options listed here. Go to http://postcodes.io/ to see the details of the API and examples. It also supports reverse lookups which is what you're after

Comment: That looks to be provided by a private company IDDQD, not the UK government.

Comment: @TonyBlundell Disclaimer: I'm the author of postcodes.io. You're 100% right, it is hosted by IDDQD. I just wanted to clarify that the underlying data used is a free UK Government alternative to Google Maps. I.e. the data is freely available to the public under the Open Government License.  Also the postcodes.io service is open sourced (MIT licensed).

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to kieran's fiddle to more to help fully answer the question of getting a UK postcode from an html5 geolocation.

```
var x=document.getElementById("output");
getLocation();

function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
       navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(reverseGeoLookup);
    }
  else
    {
       x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

function reverseGeoLookup(position) {
    console.log(position);
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
  req.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=true", true)
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == 4) {
          var result = JSON.parse(req.response).results
          for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++) {
              for(var j = 0; j < result[i].address_components.length; j++) {
                  var component = result[i].address_components[j]
                  //console.log(component.long_name);
                  if(~component.types.indexOf("postal_code")) {
                    var out = document.getElementById('output');
                    out.innerHTML = 'Approximate Post Code for your location is ' + component.long_name;
                    return false;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  req.send()
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ef72Q/28/